# Does "excepting that" here mean "but"?

Tags: phrases

In "Dr. Thorndyke's Case-Book" by Austin Freeman", a woman was talking to a detective about another killed woman, saying:

> "Oh, she liked him well enough. He is a tall, good-looking man—though for that matter he is no taller than her husband, nor any better-looking. Both men are over six feet. But **there was no harm so far as she was concerned**, **excepting that** she didn't see the position quite soon enough. She wasn't very discreet, in fact I thought it necessary to give her a little advice.

Does it mean "**she thought that** there no harm, **but** she didn't see the position quite soon enough"?

Comment: _There was no harm... excepting that..._ The only harm in the wife's liking another man was that she didn't understand 'the position' soon enough (perhaps that he was getting too fond of her?)

Comment: Yes, that's right. Thank you so much

Comment: @KateBunting So there was no harm "for" her, except that....?

Comment: I haven't read the story, but I take it to mean that there was no harm in the situation (a married woman becoming friendly with another man) except...

Comment: A former passage said "and he seemed to be very much smitten with this wife". So you are right. Thank you so much